# Unpinning the accepted answer from the top list of the answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Recently, [it was announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/383809) that there is a technical capability to unpin the accepted answer from the top list of answers.

**Now**: if the accepted answer has a lower score than other answers, it is still shown on top of the others.

**Proposed**: It will depend on the community decision.

**Action needed**: We need to decide, whether we want for Computational Science Stack Exchange the accepted answer to be pinned on top or not.

Please vote (before September 18th) for one of the answers below (and\or add comments if necessary).

---

As of Sep 19, the community supported the unpinning of the accepted answer. I posted the answer on the [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369999/383809) and updated the [overall results table for all communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/383809).

The answers underneath this question are locked. If you want to continue the discussion of the issue and express opinions, suggestion, please, start a new [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Comment: I think the way that you wrote the options had a bias. "regardless" is almost always considered a negative word and that could have had a negative impact on the "keep pinned" option, plus your "unpin" option has more detail. Later I noticed that you commented "+1 from me" on the "unpinned" case, which not only may have influenced people further, but it also confirms my suspicion that there may have been an unintentional "bias" in the way these answers were written. Furthermore, 4-1 is not really much to say there's consensus, and it's ironic that you pinned the answer saying we should unpin!

Comment: Furthermore, the decision was made here before the end of day on 19 September, but we should have until mid-October: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19742/676348. Locking the voting at a stage where you like, also seems a little bit problematic in terms of hearing what the community has to say :)

Comment: @user1271772 I locked the voting as the original deadline was. The original post (on Stack Exchange Meta) did and still has the deadline. I added my comment only AFTER the lock was done. Since I was not able to vote on my post I thought AFTER THE VOTING i am able to express my vote this way.

Comment: If you are interested in discussing this, I would suggest raising a separate topic.

Comment: The original Meta post says "We are going to collect feedback before the **end** of September 19th." but it seems you made the decision at 16:30 UTC on September 19th?

Comment: @user1271772 since I needed time to also write a post on Meta. I also announced that I am going to collect votes here till Sep 18. Also, this was made featured for the time of the voting. So it was well advertised. The answers were made CW to allow for edits if needed. I did not assume any hidden connotation. And still do not think they do.

Comment: I see! I didn't notice that the SC deadline was 1 day earlier than the Meta deadline!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepted answers **should be unpinned** from the top list of the answers, and the order of the answers should depend on their score.

Comment: +1 vote from me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer should be **shown on top regardless of its score**.